# How to get battery remaining energy in nanowatt-hours?

Tags: android, batterymanager

How can I get battery remaining energy in nanowatt-hours, average battery current in micro amperes and so on from `BatteryManager` on android versions lower than 5.0?  Because constants like `BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER`,`BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_AVERAGE` was added only from API 21. I looked in BatteryManager `public int getIntProperty (int id)` and found native classes, so I do not know how to use them.